# PHP + MsSQL = Checkbox problems. Need HELP!

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have been working on this one topic for weeks. I'm creating a webpage that pulls information from MsSQL server. My problem is where there is a section with few check boxes. 
The checkboxes are suppose to be checked if they are found in the SQL database. 
If the borrower used money from "Savings", "Checking" and "Stock" those checkboxes should be checked in HTML page.  In my case it is only checking whatever is on the first row of the SQL search list. So if the list has "Saving" on the first row, only the "Saving" checkbox will be checked not the rest on the list. I tried using loop (while($r->EOF)), but then it picks whatever is on the end of the list.  Here is what I am using to pull data from the SQL server.  Thank you in advance for your help. Really appreciate it!

```
function __construct($_ldid, $_lrid)

            $this->ldid = $_ldid;
            $this->lrid = $_lrid;

//$loan is defined in the PHP.class (which is shown below). 

$q = ("SELECT * FROM Tabel_name where loan_id = 885775")
$v = array($_ldid, $_lrid); 
$r = $db->Execute($q, $v); 
$this->downpaymenttype = $r->fields; //<- I think I have this line done wrong because it is suppose to store the outputs to an array. 

//So wherever the "$loan" is in HTML page, it will take the outputs from the above statement.

//The above code, which is in PHP.class file, outputs the following(or suppose to):
1    885775    Checking
2    885775    Saving
3    885775    Gift
```

In the HTML webpage, the following codes should check mark the boxes according to the outputs:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="DPS1[]" id="DPS1-{$key}" {if $loan-> downpaymenttype.downpaymentsource == "Checking"} checked {/if}/> 

<input type="checkbox" name="DPS2[]" id="DPS2-{$key}" {if $loan-> downpaymenttype.downpaymentsource == "Saving"} checked {/if}/> 

<input type="checkbox" name="DPS3[]" id="DPS3-{$key}" {if $loan-> downpaymenttype.downpaymentsource == "Gift"} checked {/if}/>
```

Only the "checking" checkbox is getting checked because that's the one on the first row.

I also tried to loop, but it is not storing in array (I guess I don't know how to use the array for session)

```
$q = ("SELECT Tabel_name FROM loan_downpaymentsource where loan_id = 885775"); 
$v = array($_ldid, $_lrid)); 
$r = $db->Execute($q, $v); 
while(!$r->EOF) { 
$this->downpaymenttype = $r->fields; 
$r->MoveNext(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a loop to go through your results before displaying and set flags.  $r->fields is only going to grab the fields for the current row.  You need to go through your entire rowset to see if the others are set.

Something like (It looks like you're using adodb or something like that)

```
$checking = false;
$saving = false;
$gift = false;

while(!$r->EOF){
    $row = $r->fields;
    switch($row->downpaymenttype){
        case 'Checking':
            $checking=true;
            break;
        case 'Saving':
            $saving=true;
            break;
        case 'Gift':
            $gift=true;
            break;
        default:
        break;
    }
    $r->moveNext();
}
```

Now on your view check the flags. I've not used smarty but you'll have to pass those flags to your template as well as I'm sure you know, and then change your checkbox lines to check if each flag is true/false.

Hope that helps!

Comment: he's right. if you are pulling columns from a database, the result comes back in an array, one item for each column. this means if you are only pulling one column, the result row will be a one item array containing that one column.

you have to keep pulling rows from the result in order to get multiple rows (each row being an array with multiple columns).

Comment: Thank  you fredley for the reply and the code and dqhendricks, really appreciated.  I am trying to use your suggestions. So far I haven't been lucky to get it to work. I will post once I have more understanding of the situtation. yes I am using smarty and adodb.